# How to change SharePoint database authentication

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, authentication

I created a web application and specified SQL authentication. How can I change it to NTLM?

I tried under Central Administration > Application Management > Content Databases

but that only changes the credentials for the previously selected authentication.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint?

Comment: MOSS 2007... sorry I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for:

Central Administration > Application Management > Authentication Providers

Comment: Nope, I need to change how the SharePoint service logs in to the database. Instead of using SQL authentication, I need to set it to Windows authentication.

Comment: Ah - misunderstood. I don't think what you're after is possible (though I'd love to be wrong). Maybe a site collection export/import into a new content DB could serve as a workaround?